# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_5 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape ()

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, data-science-model

I am trying to load a densenet-121 model pretrained on imagenet weights and train on my dataset. I have two files namely train.csv and validation.csv and I have splitted the train.csv file into 80-20 train set and validation set and using validation.csv file for testing. However, when I am trying my model to fit the dataset, I am getting the above error. Here is my code snippet:

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121
import collections
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.data import TFRecordDataset
model = DenseNet121(include_top=False, weights='imagenet',  input_shape=(input_shp_img),  
        classes=class_names)
_DATA_DIR = "C:/Users/1024/Documents/my_file"
_TRAIN_DIR = os.path.join(_DATA_DIR, "train")
TEST_DIR = os.path.join(_DATA_DIR, "valid")
_TRAIN_LABELS_FNAME = os.path.join(_DATA_DIR, "train.csv")
TEST_LABELS_FNAME = os.path.join(_DATA_DIR, "valid.csv")
_LABELS = collections.OrderedDict({
"-1.0": "uncertain",
"1.0": "positive",
"0.0": "negative",
"": "unmentioned",
})
len(data_csv)
train_data_size= int(0.8 * len(data_csv))
val_data_size = int(0.2 * len(data_csv))
full_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(_TRAIN_LABELS_FNAME)
full_dataset = full_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=800)
train_dataset = full_dataset.take(train_data_size)
val_dataset = full_dataset.skip(train_data_size)
val_dataset = val_dataset.skip(val_data_size)
print(train_dataset)
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
      loss='mean_squared_error',
      metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_dataset, batch_size=1000, validation_data=val_dataset, 
          steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=100, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

Below is the error I am getting:

```
ValueError   Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-117-bf00f479a1f4> in <module>
      2           loss='mean_squared_error',
      3           metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 4 history = model.fit(train_dataset, batch_size=1000, validation_data=val_dataset, 
    steps_per_epoch=100, epochs=100, use_multiprocessing=True)
      5 

~\.conda\envs\manpreet_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, 
 x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, 
 class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, max_queue_size, 
 workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
774         steps=steps_per_epoch,
775         validation_split=validation_split,
--> 776         shuffle=shuffle)
777 
778     # Prepare validation data.

~\.conda\envs\manpreet_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in 
_standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, 
steps, validation_split, shuffle)
2380         feed_input_shapes,
2381         check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
-> 2382         exception_prefix='input')
2383 
2384     if y is not None:

~\.conda\envs\manpreet_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_utils.py in 
standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
351                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
352                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
--> 353                            'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
354         if not check_batch_axis:
355           data_shape = data_shape[1:]

ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_5 to have 4 dimensions, but got ar
```